# Compression valve

Tags: plumbing

My bathroom sink and tub share the same supply line. I replaced the compression valve for the hot water and I think I over tightened it and had a bad leak under the tub, I loosen the nut and it stopped.

What caused it to leak?

Answer (score 1):

Compression fittings are a snug fit type device. They only need to be tightened until they seal. Overtightening only causes leaks.

If it is no longer leaking you are good. Monitor for leaks at frequent intervals until you trust the fitting.

Good luck!